# Audit OSQL command shutting down a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, audit, shutdown

I need to determine when, and by whom, a SQL Server was shutdown using the `osql` command. The `osql` command takes user name and password input. Are there any specific Windows Event logs generated to identify the user, time etc.?

Comment: I think you mean a T-SQL `SHUTDOWN` executed by any application using SQL authentication, not just OSQL (long deprecated). The provided SQL login will be recording the SQL Server error log along with the time. If you are looking for additional information, add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) if you are using [the T-SQL `SHUTDOWN` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to shut down SQL Server, you see see the details with username in two places:

#### SQL Server Error Log

> Date      3/15/2020 7:44:16 PM Log        SQL Server (Archive #1 - 3/15/2020
>   7:44:00 PM)
>
> Source        spid67
>
> Message Server shut down by NOWAIT request from login
>   domaninName\Username.

#### Windows Event Log

> Event Id: 6006
>
> Server shut down by NOWAIT request from login domaninName\Username.

---

If you are stopping SQL Server from configuration manager, services in the control panel or command prompt, you will only get the stop time but not the user who initiated the stop command.